# A function works when I test it with Postman, but doesn't work from my client

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, mongoose

I have a button in my client that needs to delete a document from a MongoDB collection based on ID. This is what it looks like on the backend:

index.js:

```
router.post('/deletetask', async function (req, res, next) {
  let result = await dbModule.deleteTask(req.body.taskID);
  res.json(result);
});
```

dbModule.js (that I created)

```
deleteTask: (taskID) => {
        return Task.findByIdAndDelete({_id: taskID});
    }
```

Running this through Postman returns a result and indeed deletes the task from the collection. I added the client side code, which looks like this:

This is the HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteTask(task._id)">Delete
  <!-- There is an SVG icon here, removed for clarity -->
</button>
```

The corresponding TS component:

```
deleteTask(taskID)
  {
    this.dbService.deleteTask(taskID).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
    this.router.navigate(['/tracker']); <!-- redirect to simulate a refresh -->
  }
```

The service code:

```
deleteTask(taskID):Observable<any>
  {
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/deletetask", taskID, httpOptions);
  }
```

When I add the client side code and try and run the function, I keep getting a "POST http://localhost:3000/deletetask 400 (Bad Request)"

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I thought it might have been a CORS thing, but I added the CORS npm package. I also have another function that adds tasks, which makes a POST call to the server, and that works fine, so do all my other calls.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is not enough information in this question to diagnose the problem. Concentrate on the HTTP, what's the difference between the HTTP request that works and the one that doesn't?

Comment: 1. You need to move the refresh call inside the subscription to make sure the HTTP request is complete before the page is reloaded. 2. Try to send the ID as an object: `this.http.post("...", { taskID: taskID }, httpOptions);`

Comment: @Liam I've checked it over plenty of times, I figured that's where the problem is, and there is no difference, at least not in the client.

Comment: @MichaelD Seems like passing as an object worked, thanks for the quick responses!

Comment: @DareRelaqz: I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding from my comment.

1. It's better either to move the routing inside the subscription's `next` or `complete` callback. That way we are sure the HTTP request is complete before routing somewhere else.
2. Based on the way you access the value in the back-end, you might actually need to send an object from the client. Try the following

```js
this.http.post("...", { taskID: taskID }, httpOptions);
```

Comment: I don't think the problem was the routing, because it was placed outside of the request function. I still don't understand why passing an object worked here (considering I can just take the value and then manually build the object before searching in my collection), but it works, so I won't complain XD

Comment: @DareRelaqz: The routing doesn't have anything to do with the issue, but only a tip to avoid any potential unwanted routings. For eg. if the request takes longer to complete and you don't want to route until the request is complete and so on.

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution:

```
return this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/deletetask", {taskID}, httpOptions);
```

Comment: Why? How does this address any of the issues?

Comment: It's bascailly what @Michael D commented, I don't know why this solves the issue but it does, so I'm not complaining. If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: The second parameter of post needs to be an object. {taskID} is the same than {taskID: taskID}